# Is it correct to say "I did yoga on the wrong side of the mat" or "I did yoga on the bottom side of the mat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Sometimes, I put my yoga mat upside-down on the floor before doing yoga. I should turn it right-side-up.

Is it correct to say "**I did yoga on the wrong side of the mat**" or "**I did yoga on the bottom side of the mat**"?.

Comment: Both are semantically correct, but it might be clearer to say "I did yoga with my mat upside down".

Comment: "I did yoga on the bottom side of the mat" suggests you were upside down or underneath the mat. People would probably be able to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, because the bottom side is the wrong side (for doing yoga)